# Cannot register GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger Background Task after Creators Update

Tags: c#, bluetooth, win-universal-app, .net-core

The background task registration code looks like this:

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = name;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundTaskClass).FullName;
var trigger = new GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger(characteristic);
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
btr = builder.Register();
```

The entry in the manifest is:

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTaskNS.BackgroundTaskClass">
  <BackgroundTasks>
    <Task Type="deviceConnectionChange" />
    <Task Type="bluetooth" />
  </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

The Register() method triggers this error:

> Access is denied.
>
> Your App does not have permission to use the Gatt Service in the
>   background. Make sure you have declared the DeviceCapability and Task
>   Type 'bluetooth' in your manifest and that the application has been
>   granted access to this device.

This only happens on Creators Update installed on the build machine and also targeting the Creators Update SDK. This worked well before we updated the SDK and the build machine.

Comment: Have you added the following Capabilities?

<Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
  </Capabilities>
 

                                 As you said it works well before we updated the SDK and the build machine, could you please tell us what SDK version that your app targeted prior?

Comment: @FangPeng-MSFT thanks for your reply. Yes, that is in the manifest as well. The SDK version we originally targeted was Anniversary Update. But there is another error after upgrading the machine to Creators Update using that SDK, so we tried migrating. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487748/background-task-registration-hangs-in-uwp-with-gattcharacteristicnotificationtri?noredirect=1#comment74108055_43487748) question from another developer that has the same exact problem when we were initially targeting Anniversary Update SDK on a Creators Update machine

Comment: @StanislavMayorov we did by not using background tasks anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

We've had the same issue with UWP app on windows 10 mobile.

We updated windows 10 mobile to build 10.0.15230.0, then deleted the app (manually on a phone) and installed it again. Now it works fine.
Also we installed last version of SDK, but I think this step can be skipped.

Comment: Good to know, but this is a preview ring isn't it? Our app is targeting PC so I'll check what the equivalent release is. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @Tyress yes. it's a preview (fast ring).

Answer (score 1):

In the compatibility section of your manifest, add this:

```
<Capabilities>
   <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: We have this code in the manifest and Tyress too. here's his comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511634/cannot-register-gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger-background-task-after-crea/45306893#comment74252827_43511634

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see it in your code sample. Could be that you need to call `RequestAccessAsync` from a UX thread on the GattDeviceService which contains the characteristic before registering your trigger.